# Making a trained classifier predict only from a set of classes out of the other classes for which it has been trained

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a trained classifier which can classify unseen data to any one of the four classes. Is there any way to limit this classifier to classify only from any two of all the classes.

Example,
Classes a classifier can allot to unseen data:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
```

I would like to limit the classifier's prediction to class 0 and 1 only. So, whenever I pass unseen data to the classifier, it should classify data to either 0 class or 1 class.

Comment: So are you positive that the upcoming data will always belong to class 0 or 1. What if the data actually belongs to class 2 or 3 and you try to predict class 1 or 0 based on probabilities, which will be small for both those classes and higher for class 2 or 3 (in most cases of good prediction)

Comment: Hmm, that is another problem with this. It is likely to ruin the prediction.

Comment: I am not able to understand the use-case in which you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No. A classifier is not somethin that 'can' classify, it 'does' classify. If the classifier says 3 there is no way to ask it for a different class scheme. If you want the classifier to have a binary scheme you must train that one. That is a different classifier then.

The only case coming to my mind - some multiclass classifiers have multiple binary classifiers under the hood. however you usually cannot acess this information.

What you can do is to overrule the classifier if you have extra knowledge. If you know classes 2 and 3 not to be in your test set you can use your likelyhood knowledge to convert those to either 0 or 1. I do explicitely discourage you to use probabilities to chose class 0 or 1 if the most probable class was 2 or 3.

Comment: dear downvoter, may i ask for a comment what is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can generate the predicted probabilities and then just use the argmax of columns 0 and 1.

Check eg http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba

Comment: I'm using `SGDClassifier` with `loss='hinge'`. It doesn't have a `predict_proba` method.

Comment: i have to downvote, as using the leftover low probabilities is a very bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible. While classification, in some methods, you get probabilities for each class. So if you have four classes, the output will be something like `[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]`, sum of which will always be one. This is called soft classification. You assign the class which has maximum probability.

There are other methods which do hard classification. In these methods you don't get probabilities but deterministic results. In this case your output will look like `[0,0,0,1]`.

The answer to your question depends on which classification method you are using. In case you are using soft classification, you can classify on the basis of the probabilities you get. Ignore the probabilities for the last two classes and only use the probabilities for the first two.

In case you are using a hard classifier, this won't be possible unless you can come up with a metric that is analogous to probability.

Comment: I'm using `SGDClassifier` with `loss='hinge'`. It doesn't support `predict_proba` method. However, I think I can use `decision_function` method to get the confidence scores and work with it to consider only the values of classes that I'm interested in. But, don't you think the predictions can go wrong in this process?

Comment: I just checked the documentation page of `SGDClassifier`. It has a `predict_proba` method. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict_proba

Comment: I tried that. When I ran the code, it threw an error, `AttributeError: Probability estimates are not available for loss='hinge'`.

Comment: i have to downvote, as using the leftover low probabilities is a very bad idea.